# "Smarty: unable to write file ./templates_c/" on smarty_internal_write_file.php on line 44

Tags: php, wordpress, permissions, relative-path, smarty3

i'm tring to implement Smarty template on wordpress, and i have this problem:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught  --> Smarty: unable to write file
>   ./templates_c/wrt531ad24297cbc2.21519452 <-- \n  thrown in
>   /var/www/afric-edu/library/Smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_write_file.php
>   on line 44

I first thought about permission problem and i tried this:

> chmod -R 777 /library/Smarty

but no results...
maybe this is related to a history of absolute and relative links ? Have you an idea ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the root folder is `/var/www/html/`, The following SELinux commands will fix the issue

```
# semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www/html/ow_smarty/templates_c(/.*)?"
# restorecon -Rv /var/www/html/
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right(almost), this is permission problem.

You need to allow Smarty to write to directories where it stores compiled templates `./templates_c/` in your case.

Answer (score -1):

First check templates_c folder exists and the path of `$this->setCompileDir()` in your Smarty class. Then give to Smarty the permissions: `chmod -R 777 templates_c`

Comment: You should almost never set permissions wide open to 777.  The official Smarty website suggest 644 for files and 755 for directories.
https://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=4500  <-- See the first post.